# How do I add a script to start up functions?

Tags: bash, scripts, startup-applications

I'm extremely new to Linux style computing. Please keep that in mind.

I figured out how to write a script for the calendar to pop up in the terminal.

```
#!/bin/bash
#Shell Scrip to display current date, calendar, and number of users
echo "Today is $(date)"
echo ""
echo "Calendar : "
cal
```

Super simple stuff.

Now, I want to add this to some type of startup. I want the terminal to pop up when I log into my computer every day.

I've tried System -> Preferences -> Startup Applications
 Then I click on add. I have no idea what to put in the command box.

I've also tried `/etc/init` and writing a script in there. Did something wrong there. Not sure what.

I have no idea how to use gnome.

I can't `sudo` into my box due to not having permission and I don't have upstart.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: This is "Ask **Ubuntu**", CentOS is off-topic here. It should be asked on [unix.se] instead.

Comment: ByteCommander is 100%. As for non booting upstart, boot into recovery shell, change whatever files you changed, and reboot

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When adding an application at the Startup Applications screen, enter the full path to your script into the command box. This should then run your script on startup.

**Update:**

If you want your terminal to open automatically on start-up create a start-up application and add the command to your terminal to the command field. E.g. `gnome-terminal` if you use the Gnome terminal.

Comment: So I would just type /bin/bash/calendar.sh into the command box?

Comment: Yes - and remember that the script needs to be executable.

Answer (score 1):

Ok, here is a simple trick that you will be interested:

You will be looking on a command called:

`x-terminal-emulator -e /your/script/location`

But the problem is that if your program doesn't halt it will not display and the terminal will close immediately after the script execution so you can always pause the program after you want.

```
#!/bin/bash
# init
function pause(){
   read -p "$*"
}

# Your main script
# call it
pause 'Press [Enter] key to continue...'
# rest of the script if any
# ...
```

And now you already know how to add it on startup application you can add following to command: `x-terminal-emulator -e /your/script/location` and then you are done.

Make sure you have `chmod +x script.sh` for your program.

Answer (score 0):

`/etc/rc.local` is your best friend for this kind of function at booting up instead of having to fire off the commands at terminal every time.  How this works: `/etc/rc.local` is the file where the system will look at for any specific customized scripts to execute during booting up.  There's a instruction in that file how to get it working.

Comment: I don't have permission to edit rc.local. It says: W10: Warning: Changing a readonly file.